# I can not run c++ code in code blocks, what to do?

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I created a simple program and according to the video lecture I needed to built the file after that I can run the file but when I click the run icon an popup message asking to built the program, so by clicking the yes button that popup window closes but it didn't run the code and this problem occurs again and again and I can not run the program

How can I overcome this problem?
this is my code:

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
        int main(){
            int num1, num2, sum,op;

            cout<<"This a simple calculator using c++ language "/n"Enter 
            any two numbers one by one:";
            cin>>num1>>num2;
            cout<<"There are 4 operations in this calculator->"/n"Enter 
            the respective number"/n<<"1. Addition"/n"2. 
            Subtraction"/n"3. Multiplication"/n"4. Division";
            cin>>"Operation">>op;
            if(op = 1){
                sum = num1+num2;
                cout<<"The addition of the given numbers is "<<sum;
            }
            else if(op = 2){
                sum = num1 - num2;
                cout<<"The subtraction of the given numbers is"<<sum;
            }
            else if(op = 3){
                sum = num1 * num2;
                cout<<"The multiplication of the given numbers is"<<sum;
            }
            else if(op = 4){
                sum = num1 / num2;
                cout<<"The division of the given numbers is"<<sum;
            }
            else{
                cout<<"Oop!! an error occurred... try again."
            }
    }
```

Comment: I'm not an expert at CodeBlocks, but have you configured a toolchain to use?

Comment: Your post as too litle information to go on, at least shows us the program, or if it's too large a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of it. My guess is that the program runs and closes without you realizing it, ask for an input at the end of the program, before return.

Comment: Try a small hello world program for checking and then go for other codes!!!!

Comment: Why such a question without any information, error message, problem description is still open and get answers... Nobody knows what is happening but there are assumptions what all may be happened... why? Please vote to close as long we got no information!